# Menu Drop down aparece atrás de outro objeto

Tags: dropdown

Boa tarde pessoal. Estou a criar um site no wordpress mas notei que o menu drop down aparece atras dos objectos. Este é o site: www.midbourg.com. por exemplo, clique no menu "contacte-nos", depois de entrar na pagina contacte-nos, clique no menu "produtos". O menu aparecerá atrás do campo de texto. Alguem pode me ajudar??

Comment: tenta colocar um `z-index: 9999;` na `<ul class="sub-menu"` ou na pai dela

Comment: Leandro edite sua pergunta e poste o trecho do seu código que contenha o DropDown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define a propriedade `z-index: 999` na `<ul class="sub-menu"`. E coloca o `background-color: white` tbm.

Comment: Deu certo Matheus mas surge outro problema: Quando acessas o Site pelo telefone, o menu sobrepõem o logótipo

Comment: Só colocar um `padding-bottom: 60px` na `div.custom-header` em uma media query para mobile! tipo `@media (max-width: 478px) { ... }`

Comment: Matheus, muito obrigado cara. Me ajudaste muito.

Comment: Mas preciso de mais ajuda Matheus